# Time limit exceeding in test case for my solution.What is wrong with my solution?

Tags: c++

Codeforces problem 119A-http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/119/A

My solution:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int a,b,i,n;
int gcd(int x,int y)
{
    int z,c;
    c=min(x,y);
    for(i=1;i<=c;i++)
    {
        if(((x%i)==0)&&((y%i)==0))
        z=i;
    }
    return z;
}
int main()
{
    cin>>a>>b>>n;
    while(1)
    {

        if(n<gcd(a,n))
        {
            cout<<"1";
            break;
        }
        else
        n-=gcd(a,n);
        if(n<gcd(b,n))
        {
            cout<<"0";
            break;
        }
        else
        n-=gcd(b,n);
    }   
}
```

I am not familiar with time constraints.My solution is giving the correct result while running on my computer in regular time.What should I change in my solution for it to run under time limit?Should I refrain from using user defined functions?
The test cases are-3,5,9 and 1,1,100.

Comment: "Should I refrain from using ... functions" No! You should improve your algorithm, then worry more about your algorithm, then worry about your compiler, then worry about micro optimizations like inlining a tiny pure function

Comment: In some sense this is more a math problem than a programming problem.  If you research how to compute `gcd` efficiently, then a better program will suggest itself.  Programming isn't just about hammering out code for the first idea you get.  It's also about researching the problem you're trying to solve and finding the best algorithms for solving them, and then translating those to code.

Comment: Try calculating the gcd only once rather than twice per loop.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Calculation

Answer (score 0):

Your code is definitely accurate and results in the correct answer, but there are a few minor improvements that could be made to increase efficiency and succeed in passing the time limit.

1. **Don't calculate the GCD twice inside the while loop.** GCD is an expensive algorithm as it is, and running it twice doubles your program's overall completion time. This is probably the most important fix you can make in order for your program to not result in a TLE.
2. Potentially optimize your GCD algorithm, although this isn't needed to pass all testcases (shown below)

An implementation that only uses `gcd` once and passes all testcases in codeforces might look like the following (submission [here](http://codeforces.com/contest/119/submission/6448264)):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int gcd(int, int);

int main()
{
    int a, b, n;
    cin >> a >> b >> n;
    while (1) {
        n -= gcd(a, n);
        if (n == 0) {
            cout << "0" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        n -= gcd(b, n);
        if (n == 0) {
            cout << "1" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

int gcd(int u, int v)
{
    int t;
    while ((t = u % v) != 0) {
        u = v;
        v = t;
    }
    return v;
}
```